# MSDN - Question about MSDN Subscription and Microsoft Expression tools

Tags: msdn, subscriptions

Are the latest expression tools covered under a Microsoft MSDN subscription? I know in the past they were not part of MSDN downloads. I think I remember someone saying they are available now. Are these trial editions or full-blown versions?

Comment: Not to be rude, but did you bother checking the MSDN site?

Comment: Possibly he did, but the public facing MSDN bumff doesn't always match the full subscription BOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the full Expression toolset is now available from Subscriber Downloads.

I have VSTS Architecture Edition and I can download:

Expression Blend 2 (x86) - DVD (English)
Expression Design 2 (x86) - DVD (English)
Expression Encoder 2 (x86) - DVD (English)
Expression Media 2 (Mac) - DMG (English)
Expression Media 2 (x86) - DVD (English)
Expression Studio 2 (x86) - DVD (English)
Expression Web 2 (x86) - DVD (English)

Expression Blend 1 (English)
Expression Studio 1 (English)
Expression Web 1 (English)
Expression Web 1 Service Pack 1 (x86) - EXE (English)

However, the MSDN Subscription comparison page lists only Blend and Web under Architecture and Developer Edition. VSTS Team Suite is supposed to be required for Expression Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The only ones I have available through my MSDN subcscription are Expression Blend 2 and Expression Web 2, so the entire suite is not standard to subscriptions but can be purchased. The Blend and Web are the full-blown versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am also seeing the full Expressions Suit available from the Microsoft MSDN Subscription download site. These are the full version not trials.

I just checked and these are the programs available for download:

Expression Blend 2 (x86) - DVD (English)

Expression Design 2 (x86) - DVD (English)

Expression Encoder 2 (x86) - DVD (English)

Expression Media 2 (Mac) - DMG (English)

Expression Media 2 (x86) - DVD (English)

Expression Studio 2 (x86) - DVD (English)

Expression Web 2 (x86) - DVD (English)

But I have the Universal MSDN Subscription.